# Should my JSON reponse contain the request query parameter's value?

Tags: api-design

Should I include the input query parameter in the response?

Let's say that I have an endpoint which returns people's names. I am allowing my client to filter the result by country.

I wonder, should I include the country property in the response or not, even though it matches what the client requested.

For example when the user sends the below request

/people?country=UK

should I return

```
[{"name":"tom"},{"name"="tim"}]
```

or

```
[{"name":"tom","country":"UK"},{"name":"tim","country":"UK"}]
```

as the response?

Comment: I think it will come down to convention. Maybe for some JSON end points in your app you will want a node in your response that describes the request the user made. Maybe others you won't.

Comment: I'd let the client decide on what information it wants to see. Content negotiation is the key term therefore. By using a resoure like `people` and returning a predefined content, you are basically tightly binding the client to a [typed resource](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) which is against the actual REST philosophy where you try to decoulple clients from servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what data the client needs.

If you just want a way to tell the client what they requested, you could have some convention in your API that there's a top-level node that shows what the parameters in the request were that generated this reponse.

`{"requestParams":"country=UK&city=London", data: [{"name":"tom", "street":"Wallaby"}, {"name":"tim", "street":"West"}]`

But you definitely don't want to risk returning sensitive information by returning the request params.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question we should first clarify the actual intent behind REST as this is often misconceived. REST is not about clean URIs or buzzwordy like APIs, it's about decoupling clients from servers similar to Web-Browsers that are quite robust and hardly break on server changes.

In order to achieve this, the client should not have any assumptions or predefined knowledge about an API or its resources. Everything it needs to know should be learned via request-response interaction. This isn't easy to achieve but assures that on changes done on the server-side the client wont break.

Therefore, the server should include links (HATEOAS) which a client can use to perform a state change on invoking these URIs. The backing protocol (often HTTP) defines the verbs (or methods) you can perform on these URIs. To avoid coupling a client to a server, the client can send a known list of supported document formats (like i.e. `text/html` in a web-browser) to the server, and the server can pick one of the supported document types and convert the state of the resource to this format (if supported). This content-type now defines what is returned to the client. This may be the complete content of the resource just converted to the respective representation (hence representational state transfer; REST) or may just be a sub-view of some of the resources state.

There is a variety of available content-type definitions already out there but API providers are able to create their own ones or extend from other ones if needed. The drawback to custom content-types is, however, that clients need to learn these content-types in some way. Media types are though the actual knowledge base of RESTful clients and Roy Fielding also stated that most of the design effort should be put into media-types and their handling:

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.] ([Roy Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

While `application/xml` and `application/json` are quite popular and widely supported, they do not convey much semantics. Something like `application/atom+xml` or `application/hal+json` do at least support links to support on HATEOAS requirements.

So, in order to be really RESTful, you should re-use either an existing content-type like [vCard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) for your `people` information or design something new and make it publicly available so that client-implementors have a way to learn the handling of these content-types. The common vcard content-type will already define what you may return while on the custom content type you are literally free to return whatever you want, but at least a client which supports this content-type will be able to process the data further.

Comment: I don't think he was actually talking about retuning people, that was just a simplified example. And whilst another education on REST can never hurt, his actual question has nothing to do with REST.

Comment: @NicholasShanks at the time I've created the answer the OP contained the `REST` term in the title and was also flaged with the `rest` tag, which you can see in the post-revision. I agree though, that my answer might not have fully answered the OP's question or sample, though I gave the OP a hint in the comment already. I'll consider to include this comment in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw—it was I who edited it. What you wrote was great; it just didn't answer the (mis-tagged) question that was asked :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply say you should *choose a minimal representation* of your items to send with collection responses, and be consistent in returning those.

Since the query value is always going to be dependant on the underlying data of the items that end up returning, that data belongs in the representations that you return of them when the individual items are requested — i.e. /people/tom would include {"country:"UK"}. Simply decide what parts of the full item you want to include in the list.

If a query is provided that filters on a property that is not in your usual minimal representation of "person", then don't include it. If it's normally part of the person data you include in a call to /people?foo then still include it.